# HP printer won't work on Debian w/ OpenRC

Tags: debian, hplip, openrc

I have successfully converted Debian 8.7 from systemd to OpenRC via [this](ftp://linuxmafia.com/faq/Debian/openrc-conversion.html) guide.

The latter portion of the guide says this:

> Let's say you want package hplip (printing software for HP printers), a  common use-case. On a systemd-free Debian 8 "Jessie" system, package  installation unfortunately is blocked by dependency chain hplip -> policykit-1 -> libpam-systemd -> systemd. What to do?
>   In that one case, the answer is that you only think you need the hplip package, which is an omnibus desktop-oriented packaging of the HPIJS and HPLIP drivers, and therefore includes GNOME-dependency hooks. The parts you want are in more-focussed subcomponent packages printer-driver-hpcups and printer-driver-hpijs, working with CUPS or your preferred print engine.

I have installed the `printer-driver-hpijs` package, and my printer has been added to my system. However, trying to print something gives the error `hplip.plugin`. I suspect this is because the binary plugin isn't available.

**How can I get the binary plugin without systemd?**

Comment: @Fox I have, and I'm using CUPS.